# Create an index with MongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing

I'm beginner with MongoDB and i'm trying some stuff.
I want to store URL and to avoid duplicate URL I create an unique index on the url.
Like that

```
collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", type).append("unique", true));
```

But each time I launch my program the index is create again isn't it ?

Because, now my program is only inserting one url "http://site.com" and if I restart my program this url is insert again like if there isn't index.

Creating the index each time is the wrong way to handle an index ?

Here is an example of my code

```
mongo.getCollection().ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", 1).append("unique", "true"));

mongo.getCollection().insert(new BasicDBObject("url", "http://site.com").append("crawled", 0));

mongo.getCollection().insert(new BasicDBObject("url", "http://site.com").append("crawled", 0));
```

And the output:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50d627cf44ae5d6b5e9cf106"} , "url" : "http://site.com" , "crawled" : 0}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50d627cf44ae5d6b5e9cf107"} , "url" : "http://site.com" , "crawled" : 0}
```

Thanks

EDIT :

Here is my class Mongo which handle MongoDB
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

```
public class Mongo {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private DB db;
    private DBCollection collection;
    private String db_name;

    public Mongo(String db){

        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

            this.db = mongoClient.getDB(db);
            this.db_name = db;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void drop(){
        mongoClient.dropDatabase(db_name);
    }

    public void listCollections(){
        Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String s : colls) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public void listIndex(){
         List<DBObject> list = collection.getIndexInfo();

            for (DBObject o : list) {
                System.out.println("\t" + o);
            }
    }

    public void setCollection(String col){
        this.collection = db.getCollection(col);
    }

    public void insert(BasicDBObject doc){

        this.collection.insert(doc);

    }

    public DBCollection getCollection(){
        return collection;
    }

    public void createIndex(String on, int type){
        collection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject(on, type).append("unique", true));
    }


}
```

And here is my class which handle my program

```
public class Explorer {

    private final static boolean DEBUG = false;
    private final static boolean RESET = false;

    private Mongo mongo;

    private String host;

    public Explorer(String url){
        mongo = new Mongo("explorer");
        mongo.setCollection("page");

        if (RESET){
            mongo.drop();
            System.out.println("Set RESET to FALSE and restart the program.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (DEBUG) {
            mongo.listCollections();

        }

        this.host = url.toLowerCase();



        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("url", "http://site.com").append("crawled", 0);

        mongo.getCollection().ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", 1).append("unique", true));

        mongo.getCollection().insert(new BasicDBObject("url", "http://site.com").append("crawled", 0));

        mongo.getCollection().insert(new BasicDBObject("url", "http://site.com").append("crawled", 0));




        process();
    }


    private void process(){


        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("crawled", 0);

        DBCursor cursor = mongo.getCollection().find(query);

        try {
            while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(cursor.next());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll need to pass the unique value as the boolean value true, not as a string, and it's the second parameter that are options:

```
...ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", 1), new BasicDBObject("unique", true));
```

Also, I tested it manually using the mongo interpreter:

```
> db.createCollection("sa")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.sa.ensureIndex({"url":1},{unique:true})
> db.sa.insert({url:"http://www.example.com", crawled: true})
> db.sa.insert({url:"http://www.example.com", crawled: true})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.sa.$url_1  dup key: { : "http://www.example.com" }
> db.sa.insert({url:"http://www.example2.com/", crawled: false})
> db.sa.insert({url:"http://www.example.com", crawled: false})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.sa.$url_1  dup key: { : "http://www.example.com" }
>
```

There are only the two objects:

```
> db.sa.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d636baa050939da1e4c53b"), "url" : "http://www.example.com", "crawled" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50d636dba050939da1e4c53d"), "url" : "http://www.example2.com/", "crawled" : false }
```

Comment: I've tested with true as boolean but it's the same problem.

Comment: Update your question with your current code, it must be something subtle.

Comment: Yes maybe, I just added my 2 class

Comment: You didn't change your code as I had suggested. The options, like unique must be passed as a second parameter (or 3rd): more info [ensureIndex](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#ensureIndex(com.mongodb.DBObject))  Don't use .append as part of the key parameter.

Comment: Oups, I haven't seen the difference. Now it's work, thanks ;)

Comment: ensureIndex has been deprecated in favor of createIndex, which now creates an index if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your problem but I feel it's very likely that you should use `ensureIndex` instead of `createIndex` as the latter always tries to create the index while the former will only *ensure* that it exists.

Comment: I try with `collection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", 1).append("unique", true));` but it's the same problem. In fact my problem is that I have an unique index on the url, but if I insert many time the same url then I have many records and not only one.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled over this question and there are some changes since Version 3.0.0

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(keys, options)
```

> Deprecated since version 3.0.0: db.collection.ensureIndex() is now an
>   alias for db.collection.createIndex().
>
> Creates an index on the specified field if the index does not already
>   exist.

Answer (score 0):

To Use the unique index of the mongodb, you should use the method with 2 parameters where 3rd boolean parameter is for the "unique" index.

> mongo.getCollection().ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("url", 1),"unq_url", true));

Answer (score 0):

Also I see that you dont have a collection name specified in getCollection();

What collection would that select? curious

Comment: NM, i see you use setCollection() sorry